# Enabling and Disabling Download button when downloading csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

Hi I m trying to add functionality if I click on submit then csv file will be downloaded.Till the download is completed the button should not be enabled.
Basically I want to find out that download is completed or not.
Is there any way I can achieve that?
I using ASP.NET and js and html.

Comment: There is **no** reliable way to detect if a download is completed (or not) - there are a few workaround you could attempt to do, but there is the question : why? Why would you want this? Is it not to overload the back-end with requests? Are your users triple-clickers by nature (trigger happy on the mouse)? Do you request one download per CSV only?

Comment: I have this requirement that I want to block another request from user

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what platform are you using, but you can add disabled attribute to button, using the client side script you can disable it right away and upon successfull download, mark the disabled attr to false again

Comment: I m using c# as back-end and html and js as  frontend.

Comment: But how can we determine that download is completed

Comment: Are you using MVC? web forms? Blazor? or Web API behind submit button?